# Flatten pyspark Dataframe to get timestamp for each particular value and field

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I have tried to find the change in value for each column attribute in following manner :

```
windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("attribute").orderBy(df_series['time'].asc())

final_df_series = df_series.withColumn('lagdate',f.lag(df_series['time'],-1).over(windowSpec))\
.withColumn("value_lagvalue$df",(f.lag(df_series["value"],-1).over(windowSpec)))\
.withColumn("value_grp$df",(f.col("value") - f.col("value_lagvalue$df")).cast("int"))\
.filter(F.col("value_grp$df") != 0).drop(F.col("value_grp$df"))\
.select("attribute","lagdate","value_lagvalue$df").persist()
```

The output of dataframe from above code is :

```
+---------+-------------------+-----------------+
|attribute|            lagdate|value_lagvalue$df|
+---------+-------------------+-----------------+
| column93|2020-09-07 10:29:24|                3|
| column93|2020-09-07 10:29:38|                1|
| column93|2020-09-07 10:31:08|                0|

| column94|2020-09-07 10:29:26|                3|
| column94|2020-09-07 10:29:40|                1|
| column94|2020-09-07 10:31:18|                0|

|column281|2020-09-07 10:29:34|                3|
|column281|2020-09-07 10:29:54|                0|
|column281|2020-09-07 10:31:08|                3|
|column281|2020-09-07 10:31:13|                0|
|column281|2020-09-07 10:35:24|                3|
|column281|2020-09-07 10:36:08|                0|

|column282|2020-09-07 10:41:13|                3|
|column282|2020-09-07 10:49:24|                1|

|column284|2020-09-07 10:51:08|                1|
|column284|2020-09-07 11:01:13|                0|

|column285|2020-09-07 11:21:13|                1|
+---------+-------------------+-----------------+
```

I want to transform it into following structure

```
attribute,timestamp_3,timestamp_1,timestamp_0
column93,2020-09-07 10:29:24,2020-09-07 10:29:38,2020-09-07 10:31:08
column94,2020-09-07 10:29:26,2020-09-07 10:29:40,2020-09-07 10:31:18
column281,2020-09-07 10:29:34,null,2020-09-07 10:29:54
column281,2020-09-07 10:31:08,null,2020-09-07 10:31:13
column281,2020-09-07 10:35:24,null,2020-09-07 10:36:08
column282,2020-09-07 10:41:13,2020-09-07 10:49:24,null
column284,null,2020-09-07 10:51:08,2020-09-07 11:01:13
column285,null,2020-09-07 11:21:13,null
```

Any help appreciated.(Solution in `pyspark` is preferable as it is optimized in nature for large dataframe of such kind but in pandas is also very helpful).

Update:

This article seem to achieve nearly the same thing. Hope from community to help in achieving desired goal

[PySpark explode list into multiple columns based on name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47552045/pyspark-explode-list-into-multiple-columns-based-on-name)

Comment: you can group  by and use array_list() , not sure if that will help , the timestamp column will appear in a list

Comment: @dsk need to maintain sequence of timestamp for each attribute independently

Comment: @dsk updated link for some help