# Dataframe TypeError cannot accept object

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have list of string in python as follows :

```
['start_column=column123;to_3=2020-09-07 10:29:24;to_1=2020-09-07 10:31:08;to_0=2020-09-07 10:31:13;',
'start_column=column475;to_3=2020-09-07 10:29:34;']
```

I am trying to convert it into dataframe in following way :

```
schema = StructType([
    StructField('Rows', ArrayType(StringType()), True)
])

rdd = sc.parallelize(test_list)
query_data = spark.createDataFrame(rdd,schema)
print(query_data.schema)
query_data.show()
```

I am getting following error:

```
TypeError: StructType can not accept object
```

Comment: what is the output you are looking at ?

Comment: actually keywords can become column name and value of it correspondingly will be best.Something like this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47552045/pyspark-explode-list-into-multiple-columns-based-on-name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to pass that as a list while creating the dataframe as below ...

```
a_list = ['start_column=column123;to_3=2020-09-07 10:29:24;to_1=2020-09-07 10:31:08;to_0=2020-09-07 10:31:13;',
'start_column=column475;to_3=2020-09-07 10:29:34;']
sparkdf = spark.createDataFrame([a_list],["col1", "col2"])
sparkdf.show(truncate=False)

+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
|col1                                                                                              |col2                                            |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
|start_column=column123;to_3=2020-09-07 10:29:24;to_1=2020-09-07 10:31:08;to_0=2020-09-07 10:31:13;|start_column=column475;to_3=2020-09-07 10:29:34;|
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `schema = StringType()` because your rows contains strings rather than structs of strings.

Answer (score 0):

I have two possible solutions for you.

SOLUTION 1: Assuming you wanted a dataframe with just one row

I was able to make it work by wrapping the values in test_list in Parentheses and using StringType.

```
v = [('start_column=column123;to_3=2020-09-07 10:29:24;to_1=2020-09-07 10:31:08;to_0=2020-09-07 10:31:13;',
'start_column=column475;to_3=2020-09-07 10:29:34;')]


schema = StructType([
    StructField('col_1', StringType(), True), 
    StructField('col_2', StringType(), True), 

])

rdd = sc.parallelize(v)
query_data = spark.createDataFrame(rdd,schema)
print(query_data.schema)
query_data.show(truncate = False)
```

SOLUTION 2: Assuming you wanted a dataframe with just one column

```
v = ['start_column=column123;to_3=2020-09-07 10:29:24;to_1=2020-09-07 10:31:08;to_0=2020-09-07 10:31:13;',
'start_column=column475;to_3=2020-09-07 10:29:34;']


from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

df = spark.createDataFrame(v, StringType())

df.show(truncate = False)
```